# Get a specific date in a specific time zone

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to derive a given date from a DB that is in Greenwich Mean Time.  so I need to constantly account for the discrepancy.

```
DECLARE @date datetime
DECLARE @tempdate datetime = '3/1/2019'
SET @date =  @tempdate AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard 
Time'
SELECT @date
```

The above code produces a date several hours before March 1st (since I am in the U.S.).  Is there a generic way to always grab Central Time for any desired date?

Comment: Hi @John, please tell s what database do you use ? Thanks!

Comment: I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Just to check is this something you need : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=382f75139e58dbbf0d5107a426ce79ba

Comment: That produces what I have now. :)   A date several hours earlier than the hard coded date in the query,

Comment: If you are working in an environment where timezones are important, then either use UTC times throughout, or `datetimeoffset`.

Comment: The offset would have to change with Daylight Saving Time wouldn't it?  In an automated periodic report that's a pain.

Comment: UTC times don't have a DST. UTC+1 will be UTC+1 every day of the year.

Comment: I think that should work!

Answer (score 0):

IF you are trying to convert UTC time into US Central Time it is indeed normal to receive a Central time that is earlier that UTC time. Sun rises in Greenwich first and sometime later rises in Chicago, so the March begins first in UTC zone, few hours prior to doing it in Chicago. Same goes for other months! :)